# How can I programmatically edit Mail Enabled Security Groups without powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I have some Mail Enabled Security Groups in exchange that I need to programmatically add and remove users from.

Unfortunately, you can not manage Mail Enabled Security Groups using graph, and I have been instructed to not use Powershell.

I have done a bit of searching and have not come across anything that seems to fit the bill.  I was hoping that someone might have had a similar problem and have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Basic question is why such restrictions are set up.
I expect that because high permissions are required to authorize graph service principals aka azure registered application.

Anyway, most critical issue is getting right to edit groups/users.
As I understood it's native cloud deployment, not hybrid (then typical "Windows" Active Directory methods should help (and usually quite easier to get corresponding permissions)).

Update: Addtional questions:

- if we talk on Exchange OnPremieses, Hybrid or cloud native?
- what tools stack have you available? (Python, windows command line, azure shell?, C#)
- why powershell and graph are prohibited? Any specific reason?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).